# How to configure two or more network interfaces to work simultaneously on different users I log into linux

Tags: networking, internet, vpn, nic, multiple-users

I have 2 nics on my pc and I need to configure them to work simultaneously on each user I log in, one nic per user, (knowing that you can change the user and the programs of one keep running even if logged in to another user). I want to run webscraping via python and I need to use a VPN connection for each process. It's possible?

Comment: Basic i want to be able to use 2 vpn connections at same time.

Comment: Good luck with that. I have never heard of a VPN that could do that. You have a lot or research ahead of you. You should update the question.